# How to remove the error of Action Bar in eclipse - Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have used an if else condition to show if the version of the phone is greater than or equal to HoneyComb then it will show the `ActionBar` otherwise not ..
This is my `onCreate` function :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sign_up);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {           
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    editName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editName);
    editUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editUsername);
    editPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPassword);
    editEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editEmail);
    editBatch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editBatch);
}
```

But eclipse shows the error that Call requires Api level 11 (Current Min is 9)

How to ge rid of this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
```

or

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
```

above your `onCreate()` method.

So it looks like

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
@Override
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  //rest of code
```

Comment: thanx ..  the program compiled ...
Can you explain me what's the meaning of these lines ...
I used `@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)`

Answer (score 1):

how about using [SherlockActionBar](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)?.. because the `ActionBar` is available in API 11 and above, and `SherlockActionbar` provides `ActionBar` for lower API versions

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use ActionBarSherlock http://actionbarsherlock.com/ and here is tutorial http://www.slideshare.net/androidstream/action-bar-sherlock-tutorial
Then you can use:

```
ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
```